# Create a WAR from the java files using Gradle script

Tags: java, class, gradle, ant, war

My directory sturcture is,
C:\Grapher\src\ *.java
C:\Grapher\lib\ *.jar

There are many java files and many jar dependencies. I want to create a tomcat deployable WAR.
Can any one suggest me how to create a WAR using a gradle script? What are the dependencies to be included in Gradle to create a WAR.

Comment: Did you try anything yet yourself? Where did you fail while trying?

Comment: I tried using the build.gradle file which included plugin as java and war, it created a war file only of 1kb.

Comment: You should add those bits of information to the question. Especially showing your build.gradle will help answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read and understood https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html?

> The War plugin adds two dependency configurations named providedCompile and providedRuntime. Those two configurations have the same scope as the respective compile and runtime configurations, except that they are not added to the WAR archive. It is important to note that those provided configurations work transitively. Let's say you add commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0 to any of the provided configurations. This dependency has a dependency on commons-codec. Because this is a “provided” configuration, this means that neither of these dependencies will be added to your WAR, even if the commons-codec library is an explicit dependency of your compile configuration. If you don't want this transitive behavior, simply declare your provided dependencies like commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0@jar.

If you use providedCompile or providedRuntime, those dependencies will not be added to your war archive.

The folder structure you need to have in your project is:

```
app
 |-src
    |-main
       |-java
       |-webapp
```

In the java folder you add your own packages and classes. In the webapp folder you add web content if your application makes use of such items.

Comment: I have tried all possible ways from different suggestion but unable to resolve   .I am new to Gradle and java concept, i would like to know what dependencies/extra files should be included to build a war file as i have only .java files.

Comment: I have compiled all the java files which i have with the dependent jars and was able to create the class files. I would like to know what are the further steps that needs to be followed to create war.

Comment: Since you are using Gradle, use the "war" plugin and run `./gradlew build`. Then Gradle will build your war, located in build/libs/your_application.war. It would be much easier to help if we can see your gradle.build

Comment: If you don't understand how war's are packaged and what they should include, read [The Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/index.html). Romin Irani has written a useful guide on how to write [java web applications](https://rominirani.com/gradle-tutorial-part-4-java-web-applications-9f4225cc02e5) using gradle, with all code available on GitHub (https://github.com/rominirani/GradleWebAppSample)